# Scalacheck - Value map is not a member of Object A1

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I have a trait in scala named A and I am creating a case object from it named A1. Like this:

```
trait A
case object A1 extends A
```

Now, I want to create a Scalacheck `Gen` for it, so I am creating an object `GenA`, like this:

```
object GenA {
  def a: Gen[A] = for {
    value <- A1
  } yield value
}
```

But when I try to compile it, I am getting following error:

```
value map is not a member of object A1
[error]     value <- A1
[error]              ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Can anyone help me regarding this error ?

Comment: In your code, you're treating `A1` as if it were already a generator (i.e. you're using it on the right-hand side of a `<-`), but that's not the case. Try  `val a: Gen[A] = Gen.const(A1)` instead.

Comment: @Jubobs I think you should post this as an answer. :-)

Comment: As an additional info: The scala compiler will convert a for-comprehension to a chain of .map() and .flatMap(). This is why the error says `map is not a member of (...)`

Comment: @stefanobaghino Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you wanna try something this:

```
import org.scalacheck.Gen

trait A
case object A1 extends A

object GenA {
  def a: Gen[A] =
    for {
      value <- Gen.const(A1)
    } yield value
}
```

returning the generator directly..